# Alternative to Postgresql BIGSERIAL data type in Azure Database?

Tags: azure-sql-database, sqldatatypes

I am learning Azure and data analytics with Azure. Recently finished learning Postgresql.

My question is if there is an alternative to BIGSERIAL data type for Azure Databases. I ran the query (below the error in the following) and had an error. Note that this datatype exists in Postgresql and hence I am getting confused in Azure. Any alternative to BIGSERIAL?

> Failed to execute the query. Error: Column, parameter, or variable #1:
> Cannot find data type BIGSERIAL.

```
create table person (
    ID BIGSERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    first_name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    last_name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    email VARCHAR(50),
    gender VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    date_of_birth DATE NOT NULL,
    Country_of_birth VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In PostgreSQL, the `SERIAL` keyword is used to setup an auto increment column, this works similar to auto increment in SQL. `BIGSERIAL` is an auto-incremented **Bigint** column of **8 bytes**.

Closest, I could find "**bigserial**"in MS docs is as [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-troubleshoot-postgresql#:%7E:text=Pick%20a%20partition%20column%20with%20int%2C%20bigint%2C%20smallint%2C%20serial%2C%20bigserial%2C%20smallserial%2C)

So...you can use **BIGINT** instead, below works fins for me.

```
create table person (
    ID BIGINT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    first_name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    last_name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    email VARCHAR(50),
    gender VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    date_of_birth DATE NOT NULL,
    Country_of_birth VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
);
```

[image]